# Highlight specific string at specific place Linux

Tags: linux

Is there any way I can highlight specific text at specific places and show in terminal. The highlight part can do manually in text editor but need to show the highlight when `cat`
For example:
Before highlight
`ATGCATGGTACGTACGCTAGATGACGAT`
After highlight
**A**TGCATGGTACGT**A**CGCTAGATGACG**A**T
In text editor:
`A"highlight"TGCATGGTACGTA"highlight"CGCTAGATGACGA"highlight"T`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an answer, but when you say "highlight", do you mean something like this? In case yes, what rule should be applied for highlighting some "A" characters and some not?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi Dominique, yes, the highlight should be like that but I don't wanna apply on all A, but only some A

Comment: You might check if `grep` indeed does highlighting (in my case I'm working with a Linux subsystem, not a "real" Linux). In case yes, please tell me which "A" you want highlighted, so that I can judge if a `grep` can do this.

Comment: Hi Dominique, the "A" to be highlighted is very random because it's a gene and the mutation can be anywhere. That's why I prefer to highlight manually